# MySQL Linq using .Contains(variable)

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, contains

Setup info:

- VS2013 / C#
- EF6
- MySQL database
- .Net Connector 6.9.5

I'm trying to create a method that returns a collection of Account records using a partial name as the search criteria.  If I hard code a string value using the IQueryable .Contains() extension method, it returns data.  However, when I attempt to use a variable no data is returned.

```
Public class Test() {

MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

//Works....but the search criteria is hard coded.
  public IQueryable<Account> WorksButValueHardCoded() {

    return (from a in db.Accounts
           where a.accountname.Contains("Test")
           select a);
  }

//Does not return anything
  public IQueryable<Account> DoesNotReturnAnyData() {

    //Obviously I would use a parameter, but even this test fails
    string searchText = "Test";  

    return (from a in db.Accounts
           where a.accountname.Contains(searchText)
           select a);
  }
}
```

I can see in the LINQ generated SQL used the LIKE operator, but I don't understand how the variable is injected as it reads:

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`accountid`, 
`Extent1`.`accountname`
FROM `account` AS `Extent1`
WHERE `Extent1`.`accountname` LIKE '%p__linq__0%'
```

So...why does it work with the hard coded value and not a string variable?

Comment: Please include the bug you submitted to MySQL. I am having the same issue

Comment: Here it is: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75137

Comment: Seeing same issue w/ 6.9.5, rolling back to "Install-Package MySql.Data.Entities.EF6 " which is 6.8.3 as noted by comment from @Ablue (also: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75193 and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74918 and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74943) Yuck!

Comment: yes, 6.9.3 works okay. luckily nuget has that package, oracle is less than helpful with finding it. There is certainly no sense of urgency towards fixing this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in theory i can see

**Update**

This is working fine for me on sqlServer

```
public IQueryable<Account> DoesNotReturnAnyData(MyEntities db,string searchText) {
    return (from a in db.Accounts
        where a.accountname.Contains(searchText )
        select a)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right in that the context is disposed before returning (I've since change to using a class property for the context) Using the .ToList() function does force the query. I tried it, but had the same results.  Works when hard coded, does not work when using a string variable.

Comment: I know there were some changes to the .Contains, .StartsWith, & .EndsWith extensions in the latest .Net connector for MySQL that had to do with the use of the keyword 'LIKE'.  I'm almost wondering if this is a new bug.  Is there another way to do the same thing that I could test?

Comment: Just updated, the above works fine on SQL server, you could be right, however i don't use mysql so i cant test that for you unfortunatly

Comment: I guess you could try StartsWith or even just a straight comparison Ie == with your searchText, see what happens

Comment: where a.accountname.StartWith(searchText) Fails

Comment: Marking your answer as correct because you've verified the syntax is not the problem...must be the connector.

Comment: I've logged a bug with MySQL

Comment: It looks like a bug with MySQL connector. Contains does not work.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem and followed the error step by step with Glimpse (nice tool to inspect what the server is doing). It turned out that the SQL-Statement is built correctly, because I got results by executing it on the database.
The problem could be the replacement of the string variables in the statement. I guess LINQ isn't replacing just the string you pass but fills the variable with spaces to the VARCHAR limit so your query looks like

```
SELECT`Extent1`.`accountid`, `Extent1`.`accountname`
FROM `account` AS `Extent1`
WHERE `Extent1`.`accountname` LIKE '%Test                ...       %'
```

Add

```
.Trim()
```

to your string and it works.

```
public IQueryable<Account> DoesNotReturnAnyData() {
    string searchText = "Test";

    // Use Trim() here
    return (from a in db.Accounts
       where a.accountname.Contains(searchText.Trim())
       select a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug with MySQL Entity Framework 6.9.5

Bug #74918 : Incorrect query result with Entity Framework 6:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74918

It has been fixed in MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.7 / 6.8.5 / 6.9.6 releases.

Changelog:
With Entity Framework 6, passing in a string reference to the "StartWith"
clause would return incorrect results.

Alternatively, a workaround is to use `.Substring(0)` which forces Entity not to use `LIKE` (might affect performance).

```
return (from a in db.Accounts
    where a.accountname.Contains(searchText.Substring(0))
```