# C# MySQL Connector LIKE operator is not working

Tags: c#, mysql

Looks like I found a bug:

I have the tables

```
Users 1 <---> * Customers
```

and now I want to get the specific type of the `Users`, whose `Customers` contain some text in the `Name` or `Surname` column:

```
var result = (from x in Query()
              where x.UserTypeID == 123
                   &&
                   (
                      x.Customer.Name.Contains(myString)
                       ||
                      x.Customer.Surname.Contains(myString)
                   )
              select x)
             .ToList();
```

I ran by myself the SQL query generated by that code and I saw some rows **exist**. But, the compiler returns an empty list. Why ?

This is the generated SQL query

```
SELECT
    `Filter1`.`ID`, 
    `Filter1`.`UserTypeID`, 
    `Filter1`.`CustomerID`
FROM (
    SELECT
    `UL`.`ID`, 
    `UL`.`UserTypeID`, 
    `UL`.`CustomerID`
    FROM `Users` AS `UL`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `Customer` AS `CUST` ON `UL`.`CustomerID` = `CUST`.`ID`
    WHERE `UL`.`UserTypeID` = 123
) AS `Filter1`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `Customer` AS `Extent3` ON `Filter1`.`CustomerID` = `Extent3`.`ID`
WHERE (`Filter1`.`Name` LIKE '%p__linq__0%') OR (`Extent3`.`Surname` LIKE '%p__linq__1%')
```

I changed the `p__linq__0` and `p__linq__1` to e.g. `a` and I saw some results

Comment: How would we reproduce this?

Comment: What SQL do you expect this to generate? What does it generate? Which MySQL Connector do you use?

Comment: Duplicate of [MySQL Linq using .Contains(variable)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338108/mysql-linq-using-containsvariable). Downgrade your MySQL connector or use `myString.Trim()`.

Comment: CodeCaster >> It works now, thanks !